# Magento order mail copy configuration

Tags: magento2, email, order-email

I try to change on the admin the mail address on where a copy of the mail order confirmation is send, but I can't find where and I can't update it..

Someone can help me ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[How to Configure Sales Email in Magento 2](https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-configure-sales-email-magento-2.html)

1. On the Admin Panel, `Stores > Settings > Configuration`.
2. On the left panel, under Sales tab, click on `Sales Emails` subtab.
3. Open the Order section:

   - To send the sales emails to many people at the same time, enter the
     **email addresses** in the **Send Order Email Copy To field**, and each is
     separated by comma.

Comment: I saw this page but all the fields are gray and I want to update the address...

Comment: `Use system value` checkbox uncheck and add your email address

Comment: Is impossible to uncheck this field...

Comment: yes this field for multistore

Comment: I added the screenshot

Comment: uncheck checkbox and enter email

Comment: Is impossible to uncheck this field...

Comment: yes bro why not ?

Answer (score 0):

Add the email address at this location in the backend.
1) Go to System Configuartion.
2) Open the sales tab and select Sales Email.
3) Expand the Order tab.
4) Add the order emails to Send Order Email Copy To

Comment: I saw this page but all the fields are gray and I want to update the address...

Comment: Please add the screenshot.

Comment: Added :) Thanks for the help

Comment: Uncheck the check box of Use System value.

Comment: Is impossible to uncheck this field...